# What is the span of linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If we have linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$ such as  $a=(0, 3, 0, 0)$, $b=(1, 0, 0, 0)$, $c=(2, 0, 0, 0)$ and $d=(0, 2, 0, 5)$, what would be their span in $\mathbb{R}^4$?
And can we somehow generalize this question for all spaces?

Comment: What kind of answer are you expecting? I could answer this question, for example, by applying the definition of span: the span consists of all vectors of the form $$ra + sb + tc + ud = (0,3a,0,0) + (s,0,0,0) + (2t,0,0,0) + (0,2u,0,5u) = (s+2t,3a+2u,0,5u)$$ Presumably that's not what you want, but I'm not sure exactly what you *would* want.

Answer (score 1):

If four vectors in four dimensional space are linearly dependent then their span is some subspace of lower dimension. That's about all you can say.

By analogy and for example: the span of two linearly dependent vectors in the plane will be a line through the origin (or just the origin itself if both vectors happen to be the zero vector).

Comment: So the span of mentioned vectors is not R^4 itself, but a space with lower dimension?

Comment: @Karen Correct! But you should be able to determine in your example what lower dimension that is by, for instance, reducing the matrix to Gauss-Jordan form. This will more easily show you how many linearly independent vectors you have.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a trick you might like: put the vectors as the columns of a matrix and row reduce.  Elementary row operations do not change the dependence of the columns.  But it will be easy to read off a basis for the column space of the row reduced matrix.  The trick now is that the corresponding columns in the original matrix will form a basis for the original column space.

Be careful though, the column space of the row-reduced matrix is in general different than that of the original matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this process: Let $n\geq1$. If $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}^N$, then set
$F_1=\text{span}\{x_1\}$. Check if $x_2\in F_1$. If so, set $F_2=F_1$. If $x_2\not\in F_1$, set $F_2=\text{span}\{x_1,x_2\}$.

Then check if $x_3\in F_2$. If so, set $F_3=F_2$. If not, set $F_3=\text{span}\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$.... and so on. When you have exhausted $\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}$, check how many vectors span $F_n$. This is the dimension of the space that $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ span.

Comment: even if $n\geq N$, the dimension of the linear span of $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ will always be at most $N$. Keep this in mind.

In your case: $F_1=\text{span}\{a\}$. Obviously $b\not\in F_1$, so $F_2=\text{span}\{a,b\}$. Now $c=2b$, so $c\in F_2$, so $F_3=F_2$. Finally, if $d\in F_3$, then
$(0,2,0,5)=t_1x+t_2b=(t_2,3t_1,0,0)$, which is impossible for all values of $t_1,t_2$. So $d\not\in F_3$, thus $F_4=\text{span}\{a,b,d\}$. The dimension of $\text{span}\{a,b,c,d\}$ is therefore $3$.